# How to register all selected entries from a QListView inside a wizardpage?

Tags: c++, qt, wizard

I've got a QListView inside a wizardpage. There are several entries and multiple selection is active. I want the selected items beeing registered as a field when the 'next' button is clicked.

Is it possible? And if how, cause registerfield can't work, connect() nedds an modelindex,
iterating over the model-rows doesn't work in wizardpage:initializePage().

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe is not the nicest solution, but it works just fine:

Add a property to the wizardpage which contains the `QListView` and let it return the pointer to the selectionmodel. E.g. like this:

```
class ListPage : public QWizardPage
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(QItemSelectionModel* selectionModel READ selectionModel)

public:
   ListPage(QWidget * parent = NULL);
   QItemSelectionModel * selectionModel(void)
   {
      return listView->selectionModel();
   };
private:
   QListView *listView;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QItemSelectionModel*);
```

In the constructor of ListPage you then have to call `qRegisterMetaType` and `registerField` like so:

```
ListPage::ListPage(QWidget * parent) : QWizardPage(parent)
{
   ...
   listView = new QListView(this);
   listView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
   listView->setModel(model);

   qRegisterMetaType("QItemSelectionModel*");
   registerField("listViewSelection", this, "selectionModel");
   ...
}
```

Now you can access the selected items from everywhere in the wizard by calling `field("listViewSelection").value<QItemSelectionModel*>()`.

Hope this is what you expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the fine explanation + code. Less talk more code :) I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Hi sorry was too deep in writing the documentation... It didn't run yet, but i'll keep on trying.

Comment: Right now the problem is to register:

qRegisterMetaType("QItemSelectionModel*");
error: ‘qt_metatype_id’ is not a member of ‘QMetaTypeId<const char>’

Qt4.6 Qt-Creator-1.3

Comment: Do you have Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QItemSelectionModel*) somewhere in your includes?